# Is that possible to run iphone UIAutomation script using ad-hoc distribution build

Tags: javascript, iphone, instruments, ui-automation, ios-ui-automation

Previously i was using Developer build which support to run my **UIAuotmation scripts** , but recently i tried the build with ad-hoc distribution provisioning file its not compatible to run my  **UIAuotmation scripts**.

can any one please explain me why this is happening???

Answer (score 0):

UIAutomation is part of instruments, it is a developer/debugging tool. Ad-hoc distributions are for installing on selected devices from iTunes without the developer suite. It is normal for an ad-hoc distribution build to be incompatible with UIAutomation.

Comment: i guess that .IPA file consist .APP file which is that ad - hoc build, then why its not supporting, can i get the exact reason.